# Azure Stream Analytics tools for Visual Studio: Error when executing aggregated queries - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-stream-analytics, complex-event-processing

We have followed the documentation [Use Azure Stream Analytics tools for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-tools-for-visual-studio) and made the Visual Studio capable of creating Azure Stream Analytics project.

We have created an Azure Stream Analytics(ASA) job with Local Input data in the following JSON format:

```
[
    {
        "Driver": "Lewis",
        "Speed": 0.8275496959686279,
        "Accelerator": 1,
        "Brakes": 0,
        "Steering": 0,
        "ErsBattery": 0.9398990273475647,
        "Gear": 0,
        "LapTimeMs": 107,
        "EventTime": "2016-04-01T00:00:00.107",
        "PosX": 1593.4061279296875,
        "PosY": 934.5406494140625,
        "PosZ": 101.44535064697266
    },
    {
        "Driver": "James",
        "Speed": 1.8795902729034424,
        "Accelerator": 1,
        "Brakes": 0,
        "Steering": 0,
        "ErsBattery": 0.9865896105766296,
        "Gear": 0,
        "LapTimeMs": 107,
        "EventTime": "2016-04-01T00:00:00.107",
        "PosX": 1593.3990478515625,
        "PosY": 934.5374145507812,
        "PosZ": 101.44610595703125
    },
    {
        "Driver": "Damon",
        "Speed": 0.4023849666118622,
        "Accelerator": 1,
        "Brakes": 0,
        "Steering": 0,
        "ErsBattery": 1,
        "Gear": 0,
        "LapTimeMs": 108,
        "EventTime": "2016-04-01T00:00:00.108",
        "PosX": 1593.411865234375,
        "PosY": 934.5435180664062,
        "PosZ": 101.44485473632812
    }
]
```

Then we are running the query **locally** as below:

```
SELECT Driver, AVG(Speed) AS AvgSpeed
FROM Input 
GROUP BY Driver, TumblingWindow(second, 10)
```

After executing the query, we are getting an error message as "**Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your Visual Studio IDE in Administrator mode, run your ASA query with **local input** and you will get the expected query result.

[image]